# how to transpose multiple column parameters without double counting

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to transpose multiple columns with different parameters into two columns. I've tried different methods mentioned in different posts on Stackoverflow,but the results always give me duplicate values and hence double counting. Any help would be much appreciated.

This the raw data:
[image]

This is the format I want my final raw data:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please include your data as text (no images/links) and indicate what you have tried already. See also [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Use [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long):

```
pd.wide_to_long(df,
                ['Geo','Target Geo'],
                ['Name','ID','user_name','platform','ID2','Placement Name','ID3'],
                j='Codes',
                sep=' ',
                suffix='.')\
  .reset_index()\
  .drop('Codes',axis=1)
```

Output:

```
  Name   ID user_name platform  ID2 Placement Name    ID3 Global Target Global Geo  Target Geo
0  ABC  123       sky     blah  456             RV  56789                       US         9.0
1  ABC  123       sky     blah  456             RV  56789                       UK        10.0
2  ABC  123       sky     blah  456             RV  56789                       CN         9.0
3  ABC  123       sky     blah  456             FS  98765                       US         8.5
4  ABC  123       sky     blah  456             FS  98765                       UK         4.0
5  ABC  123       sky     blah  456             FS  98765                       DE         3.6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott. But for some reason the Target values are still not getting transposed. I only get Nan in Target Geo. I used the exact code. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Check you column headings for whitespace.  Use df.to_dict() to help identify.